# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^2+b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me in evaluating
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^2+b},
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers?

I am interested especially in the case where $|a|<1$, but I wasn't able to solve.
I think it relate to the Basel problem.

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you familiar with the digamma function?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
I'm not familiar at all...

Comment: Well Mathematica evaluates this series to equal: $\frac{\psi\left(a+\sqrt{-b}+1\right)-\psi\left(a-\sqrt{-b}+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{-b}}$ where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-PolyGamma%5B0%2C+1+%2B+a+-+Sqrt%5B-b%5D%5D+%2B+++PolyGamma%5B0%2C+1+%2B+a+%2B+Sqrt%5B-b%5D%5D%29%2F%282+Sqrt%5B-b%5D%29

Comment: Substituting $a=0$ and taking the limit as $b\to 0$ of this solution does indeed give you the solution to the Basel problem ($\pi^2/6$).

Comment: This really helps.  Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{1}{(n+a)^2+b}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a+\sqrt{-b} )(n+a-\sqrt{-b} )}$$ Use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{(n+a+\sqrt{-b} )(n+a-\sqrt{-b} )}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{-b}} \left(\frac{1}{n+a-\sqrt{-b}}-\frac{1}{n+a+\sqrt{-b}}\right)$$

Now, using generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{1}{n+c}=H_{p+c}-H_c$$ and when $p$ is large
$$=H_{p+c}-H_c=-H_c+\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{2c+1}{2p}-\frac{6 c^2+6c- -1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Apply it twice and continue with Taylor series
$$S_p=\frac{H_{a+\sqrt{-b}}-H_{a-\sqrt{-b}}}{2 \sqrt{-b}}-\frac 1 p+\frac{2 a+1}{2 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ Therefore
$$S_\infty=\frac{H_{a+\sqrt{-b}}-H_{a-\sqrt{-b}}}{2 \sqrt{-b}}$$ If $b >0$,we have harmonic numbers of complex arguments which will simplify to some hyperbolic  cotangents.

For example $a=2$, $b=3$ lead to
$$\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right)}{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{47}{84}$$

For the case where $a$ is small, series expansion gives
$$S_\infty=\frac{\pi  \sqrt{b} \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{b}\right)-1}{2 b}+\frac{ \left(\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\sqrt{-b}+1\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(1-\sqrt{-b}\right)\right)}{2
   \sqrt{-b}}a+\frac{ \left(1-\pi ^3 b^{3/2} \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{b}\right)
   \text{csch}^2\left(\pi  \sqrt{b}\right)\right)}{2 b^2}a^2+O\left(a^3\right)$$

Trying for $a=\frac 13$ and $b=4$, the exact result is $0.584675\cdots$ while the truncated series leads to $0.584226$